# Hibernate one to one criteria fetching

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using hibernate one to one mapping between car and person table. But a person might have car and might not have a car. now while fetching the records from the person table using hibernate criteria , I want to fetch only those persons who have a car, i.e only those entries in person table for which a corresponding entry in car table exists. How this can be done using hibernate criteria/alias?

Below is the piece of code. kindly help with the criteria or alias that has to written to fetch result:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "Person")
public class Person implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "Person_ID")
    private Long personId;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "personAsset", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Car car;
}

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "Car")
public class Car implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "Car_ID")
    private Long carId;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "Person_ID")
    private Person personAsset;
}
```

Comment: did you try to work wirh JPQL ? a simple Query will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

what you are looking for is the cascadeType `orphanRemoval=true` on the `@OneToOne` annotation.

here is your class how would look like :

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "Car")
public class Car implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "Car_ID")
    private Long carId;

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER , cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "Person_ID")
    private Person personAsset;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Person> query = cb.createQuery(Person.class);
Root<Person> person = query.from(Person.class);
Predicate predicate = cb.isNotNull(person.join("car"));
predicates.add(predicate );
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please add some explanation to your answer.